# Generate type out of multiple objects in array

Tags: typescript

I want to make my End-to-End testing easier and typesafer, by collecting and transforming the data-attributes in a typed constant object.
However, I cannot make it work.

How can I create an union type out of an attribute value of multiple objects within an array?

```
interface Itest {
  name: string
  values: readonly string[]
}

const testAttributes: readonly Itest[] = [
  {
    name: "testid",
    values: [
      "playbarQueueIcon",
      "queueBar",
      "playbarPlayButton",
      "playbarPauseButton",
      "playbarPreviousButton",
      "playbarNextButton",
      // ...
    ] as const,
  } as const,
  {
    name: "testgroup",
    values: ["queueNextTracks", "queuePreviousTracks"] as const,
  } as const,
] as const

// ***********************
// Why does this not work?
// ***********************
type ITest = typeof testAttributes[number]["values"][number]


const attr = testAttributes.reduce((acc, {name, values}) => {
  for (const value of values) {
    acc[value] = `[data-${name}=${value}]`
  }

  return acc
}, {} as Record<ITest, string>
)

attr.queueBarXXXX // => Should not work
attr.queueBar // => Should work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually setting a type via `: readonly Itest[]` overrides what could be inferred.  So `values` is `string[]` because that overrides the `as const` assertion. Remove that and you get the union I think you expect.

If you want `testAttributes` to *satisfy* the `Itest[]` type but be inferred to something more specific you need to wait for the `satisfies` operator to land in released typescript: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920

Or use a function:

```
function makeTestArray<T extends Itest[]>(arr: T): T { return arr }
const testAttributes = makeTestArray([...]) // data goes here.
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKQM5mQbwFDLIhwC2EAXMllKAOYHIBucANgK4QaVQRwAmAexAsAnlTA0QtANoBdPAF88eGGxAIwwIchJwA1hAAqnMAEEoUOCIA8h5BAAekEHwzIe-IaLSYwcgHwAFHAWlIYAlGG47hBgbFAgyCFQyEp4CEJYyL6mYBLAAEZsmMgAvDr6RibmliKB0gz4hITEZJQARL7AfO0ANAyEzOyclA3Nze0ADixWBSEAihwcqBkgfQMTAI5LEABCIevjhFMzInNQAAqnu8VgQodHJ7MhF3BsGHu39-1HyE9nLx4jC07xueW+G2O02eUAAco4wGC7msfkcAPRo5AAOhxG1kSTcqywqIUBOQRLAqKazVaFD+vloUAEbEmD0GrA4XGQ0na2wgHHhTkMlgQegwfT+fI4FyBIIwwsQYva+LghMylIYpNV5PV-RVapAWHCyjwYBEkxQqGMWXKZotAhg2WqeRoRUw0hAbBIBWgsh5Q05yo9Xp9UHkGL+0IBUEW-IgK3uyAAPpKdvsoO1k5HTucrlYkYmU-9c28PgW1lni4CIMDmRhy5mi1HzoLEV8K0WpRBWwrReLK12ZTW5b2lUA)